# CSS or jQuery height inheritance problems

Tags: jquery, css, inheritance, height

I'm having a problem with content heights inside a box that acts as a border. I essentially have an internal content box and a sidebar on top of a background box. The background box inherits it's height from the internal content box, which inherits it's height from the content itself. The problem is that because the sidebar does not have the same amount of content as the internal content box, the sidebar's height does not match the internal content box's height. I wrote a small script in jQuery to fix it, but it isn't cross-browser compatible.

```javascript
jQuery(function(){
  var pageHeight = jQuery('div#internalcontent').height();
  jQuery('div#sidebar').css('height', pageHeight);
});
```

This code works in Chrome sometimes, but usually fails in Firefox. I assume it has something do with the way the page is loading - eg all the elements aren't loaded when the page height is assigned.

Does anyone know a way to do this in CSS, or fix it in javascript? Thanks.

Comment: I fixed it by dropping that code into a function, and then using <body onload="function">.

Answer (score 0):

Call that code after $(document).ready()

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var pageHeight = $('div#internalcontent').height();
  $('div#sidebar').css('height', pageHeight);
});
```

Comment: That fixed it, at least if there are no other cached pages or anything. (I thought I fixed it once before so this is very possible) I'll keep accepting answers for a little, see if anyone has a way to do it in CSS. Thanks!

Comment: Just reloaded the page a hundred times, and the fix isn't consistent. I would say 3/5 times the page loads correctly, otherwise the heights are messed up again. Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: If the page is loading 3/5 of the times correct, that's strange... do you have a ton of other js running on the page? or maybe a firefox addon/plugin thats screwing with the page load

Answer (score 0):

@Adam `jQuery(function(){});` should produce the same behavior as the document ready handler to my knowledge. http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: Yeah I think this right, I'm having similar issues with that change.

Comment: When commenting on someones answer, then please don't make a new answer but instead really make a comment next time. :-)